# What is "fore" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

In [this post](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-unexpected-ways-that-your-employer-takes-advantage-of-you?__nsrc__=4), there's a mentioning as follows.

> Fore warned is fore armed.

I've looked it up and google told me that *fore* means following things.

1. situated or placed in front
2. the front part of something, especially a ship
3. called out as a warning to people in the path of a golf ball
4. non-standard form of before.

None of that makes sense to me in the quoted context. While I do understand the intent of it, I still feel uncertain which of the above four alternatives is the one used in sentence (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verbs "[Forewarn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forewarn)" and "[forearm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forearm)" should each be written as a single word, as should their respective past participles, "forewarned" and "forearmed."

"Forewarned is forearmed" is a well-known adage, and something of a cliché. It means that if you know about a dangerous situation in advance, you will be prepared to deal with it. (Here, "forearmed" is used metaphorically; the idea is that having information is akin to having weapons that you can use in a fight.)

Comment: Can the words be spelled separately (e.g. *fore armed*) ever? Making a stylistic choice or perhaps an archaic form? Or is it simply and plainly that the post I link to and where I obtained the quotation contains a typo?

Comment: Yes, we can safely say that those are typos or spelling errors in that post. Here's a Google Ngram comparing the frequency of "forewarned," "fore-warned," and "fore warned" over time:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Forewarned%2Cfore-warned%2Cfore+warned&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CForewarned%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bforewarned%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BForewarned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cfore%20-%20warned%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfore%20-%20warned%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFore%20-%20warned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfore%20warned%3B%2Cc0 However, …

Comment: …it looks like "fore-armed" is a bit more common in nineteenth-century texts than "fore-warned" is, though even there it is not as common as "forearmed." (I think it's likely that some writers used the hyphenated form for the verb and the single-word form for the noun.) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forearmed%2Cfore-armed%2Cfore+armed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforearmed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfore%20-%20armed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfore%20armed%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

Forewarned and forearmed are each one word.

> forewarned is forearmed
>
> PROVERB
>
> prior knowledge of possible dangers or problems gives one a tactical advantage.

Or, said another way, if you know about something before it happens, you can be prepared for it.

[Forewarned is forearmed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forewarned-is-forearmed)